# watir invalid argument error for set method

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using watir and ruby to write a page object pattern UI framework. This was working fine until I did bundle update

I have a yml file representing a page like this

```
username:
 field: text_field
 attribute: name
 value: username
 default:
 operations:
  - exists?
  - set
```

And a page object method generator which this feeds into

```
def generate(elements)
    elements.each do |element|
        element[1]['operations'].each do |operation|
            if operation.eql? 'set'
                default = element[1]['default']
                self.class.send(:define_method, "#{element[0]}_#{operation}") do |default=''|
                    @b.send(element[1]['field'], element[1]['attribute'].to_sym, element[1]['value']).send(operation, default)
                end
            else
                self.class.send(:define_method, "#{element[0]}_#{operation}") do
                    @b.send(element[1]['field'], element[1]['attribute'].to_sym, element[1]['value']).send(operation)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

When I am running watir tests against chrome this seems to be working fine. However when my browser is firefox I am getting an error `Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError)`

Line 6 in generate method is throwing that error

This is how I pass the yml to the generate method

```
def initialize(browser)
    file_path = File.expand_path("../config/signin.yml", __FILE__)
    elements = YAML.load(File.read(file_path));
    super(browser, elements)
end
```

watir version `6.8.0`
selenium-webdriver version `3.5.1`
geckodriver-helper `0.0.3`

**UPDATE**

**complete stack trace:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/02500e7f-0c52-1e40-b151-39b2d857d17f/execute/sync | {"script":"return (function(){return function(){var d=this;function f(a){return\"string\"==typeof a};function h(a,b){this.code=a;this.a=l[a]||m;this.message=b||\"\";a=this.a.replace(/((?:^|\\s+)[a-z])/g,function(a){return a.toUpperCase().replace(/^[\\s\\xa0]+/g,\"\")});b=a.length-5;if(0>b||a.indexOf(\"Error\",b)!=b)a+=\"Error\";this.name=a;a=Error(this.message);a.name=this.name;this.stack=a.stack||\"\"}\n(function(){var a=Error;function b(){}b.prototype=a.prototype;h.b=a.prototype;h.prototype=new b;h.prototype.constructor=h;h.a=function(b,c,g){for(var e=Array(arguments.length-2),k=2;k<arguments.length;k++)e[k-2]=arguments[k];return a.prototype[c].apply(b,e)}})();var m=\"unknown error\",l={15:\"element not selectable\",11:\"element not visible\"};l[31]=m;l[30]=m;l[24]=\"invalid cookie domain\";l[29]=\"invalid element coordinates\";l[12]=\"invalid element state\";l[32]=\"invalid selector\";l[51]=\"invalid selector\";\nl[52]=\"invalid selector\";l[17]=\"javascript error\";l[405]=\"unsupported operation\";l[34]=\"move target out of bounds\";l[27]=\"no such alert\";l[7]=\"no such element\";l[8]=\"no such frame\";l[23]=\"no such window\";l[28]=\"script timeout\";l[33]=\"session not created\";l[10]=\"stale element reference\";l[21]=\"timeout\";l[25]=\"unable to set cookie\";l[26]=\"unexpected alert open\";l[13]=m;l[9]=\"unknown command\";h.prototype.toString=function(){return this.name+\": \"+this.message};var n;a:{var p=d.navigator;if(p){var q=p.userAgent;if(q){n=q;break a}}n=\"\"}function r(a){return-1!=n.indexOf(a)};function t(a,b){for(var e=a.length,c=f(a)?a.split(\"\"):a,g=0;g<e;g++)g in c&&b.call(void 0,c[g],g,a)};function v(){return r(\"iPhone\")&&!r(\"iPod\")&&!r(\"iPad\")};function w(){return(r(\"Chrome\")||r(\"CriOS\"))&&!r(\"Edge\")};var x=r(\"Opera\"),y=r(\"Trident\")||r(\"MSIE\"),z=r(\"Edge\"),A=r(\"Gecko\")&&!(-1!=n.toLowerCase().indexOf(\"webkit\")&&!r(\"Edge\"))&&!(r(\"Trident\")||r(\"MSIE\"))&&!r(\"Edge\"),aa=-1!=n.toLowerCase().indexOf(\"webkit\")&&!r(\"Edge\");function B(){var a=d.document;return a?a.documentMode:void 0}var C;\na:{var D=\"\",E=function(){var a=n;if(A)return/rv\\:([^\\);]+)(\\)|;)/.exec(a);if(z)return/Edge\\/([\\d\\.]+)/.exec(a);if(y)return/\\b(?:MSIE|rv)[: ]([^\\);]+)(\\)|;)/.exec(a);if(aa)return/WebKit\\/(\\S+)/.exec(a);if(x)return/(?:Version)[ \\/]?(\\S+)/.exec(a)}();E&&(D=E?E[1]:\"\");if(y){var F=B();if(null!=F&&F>parseFloat(D)){C=String(F);break a}}C=D}var G;var H=d.document;G=H&&y?B()||(\"CSS1Compat\"==H.compatMode?parseInt(C,10):5):void 0;var ba=r(\"Firefox\"),ca=v()||r(\"iPod\"),da=r(\"iPad\"),I=r(\"Android\")&&!(w()||r(\"Firefox\")||r(\"Opera\")||r(\"Silk\")),ea=w(),J=r(\"Safari\")&&!(w()||r(\"Coast\")||r(\"Opera\")||r(\"Edge\")||r(\"Silk\")||r(\"Android\"))&&!(v()||r(\"iPad\")||r(\"iPod\"));function K(a){return(a=a.exec(n))?a[1]:\"\"}(function(){if(ba)return K(/Firefox\\/([0-9.]+)/);if(y||z||x)return C;if(ea)return v()||r(\"iPad\")||r(\"iPod\")?K(/CriOS\\/([0-9.]+)/):K(/Chrome\\/([0-9.]+)/);if(J&&!(v()||r(\"iPad\")||r(\"iPod\")))return K(/Version\\/([0-9.]+)/);if(ca||da){var a=/Version\\/(\\S+).*Mobile\\/(\\S+)/.exec(n);if(a)return a[1]+\".\"+a[2]}else if(I)return(a=K(/Android\\s+([0-9.]+)/))?a:K(/Version\\/([0-9.]+)/);return\"\"})();var L,M=function(){if(!A)return!1;var a=d.Components;if(!a)return!1;try{if(!a.classes)return!1}catch(g){return!1}var b=a.classes,a=a.interfaces,e=b[\"@mozilla.org/xpcom/version-comparator;1\"].getService(a.nsIVersionComparator),c=b[\"@mozilla.org/xre/app-info;1\"].getService(a.nsIXULAppInfo).version;L=function(a){e.compare(c,\"\"+a)};return!0}(),N=y&&!(8<=Number(G)),fa=y&&!(9<=Number(G));I&&M&&L(2.3);I&&M&&L(4);J&&M&&L(6);var ga={SCRIPT:1,STYLE:1,HEAD:1,IFRAME:1,OBJECT:1},O={IMG:\" \",BR:\"\\n\"};function P(a,b,e){if(!(a.nodeName in ga))if(3==a.nodeType)e?b.push(String(a.nodeValue).replace(/(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)/g,\"\")):b.push(a.nodeValue);else if(a.nodeName in O)b.push(O[a.nodeName]);else for(a=a.firstChild;a;)P(a,b,e),a=a.nextSibling};function Q(a,b){b=b.toLowerCase();return\"style\"==b?ha(a.style.cssText):N&&\"value\"==b&&R(a,\"INPUT\")?a.value:fa&&!0===a[b]?String(a.getAttribute(b)):(a=a.getAttributeNode(b))&&a.specified?a.value:null}var ia=/[;]+(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)(?=(?:[^()]*\\([^()]*\\))*[^()]*$)/;\nfunction ha(a){var b=[];t(a.split(ia),function(a){var c=a.indexOf(\":\");0<c&&(a=[a.slice(0,c),a.slice(c+1)],2==a.length&&b.push(a[0].toLowerCase(),\":\",a[1],\";\"))});b=b.join(\"\");return b=\";\"==b.charAt(b.length-1)?b:b+\";\"}function S(a,b){N&&\"value\"==b&&R(a,\"OPTION\")&&null===Q(a,\"value\")?(b=[],P(a,b,!1),a=b.join(\"\")):a=a[b];return a}function R(a,b){b&&\"string\"!==typeof b&&(b=b.toString());return!!a&&1==a.nodeType&&(!b||a.tagName.toUpperCase()==b)}\nfunction T(a){return R(a,\"OPTION\")?!0:R(a,\"INPUT\")?(a=a.type.toLowerCase(),\"checkbox\"==a||\"radio\"==a):!1};var ja={\"class\":\"className\",readonly:\"readOnly\"},U=\"async autofocus autoplay checked compact complete controls declare defaultchecked defaultselected defer disabled draggable ended formnovalidate hidden indeterminate iscontenteditable ismap itemscope loop multiple muted nohref noresize noshade novalidate nowrap open paused pubdate readonly required reversed scoped seamless seeking selected spellcheck truespeed willvalidate\".split(\" \");function V(a,b){var e=null,c=b.toLowerCase();if(\"style\"==c)return(e=a.style)&&!f(e)&&(e=e.cssText),e;if((\"selected\"==c||\"checked\"==c)&&T(a)){if(!T(a))throw new h(15,\"Element is not selectable\");b=\"selected\";e=a.type&&a.type.toLowerCase();if(\"checkbox\"==e||\"radio\"==e)b=\"checked\";return S(a,b)?\"true\":null}var g=R(a,\"A\");if(R(a,\"IMG\")&&\"src\"==c||g&&\"href\"==c)return(e=Q(a,c))&&(e=S(a,c)),e;if(\"spellcheck\"==c){e=Q(a,c);if(null!==e){if(\"false\"==e.toLowerCase())return\"false\";if(\"true\"==e.toLowerCase())return\"true\"}return S(a,\nc)+\"\"}g=ja[b]||b;a:if(f(U))c=f(c)&&1==c.length?U.indexOf(c,0):-1;else{for(var u=0;u<U.length;u++)if(u in U&&U[u]===c){c=u;break a}c=-1}if(0<=c)return(e=null!==Q(a,b)||S(a,g))?\"true\":null;try{var k=S(a,g)}catch(ka){}(c=null==k)||(c=typeof k,c=\"object\"==c&&null!=k||\"function\"==c);c?e=Q(a,b):e=k;return null!=e?e.toString():null}var W=[\"_\"],X=d;W[0]in X||!X.execScript||X.execScript(\"var \"+W[0]);\nfor(var Y;W.length&&(Y=W.shift());){var Z;if(Z=!W.length)Z=void 0!==V;Z?X[Y]=V:X[Y]&&X[Y]!==Object.prototype[Y]?X=X[Y]:X=X[Y]={}};; return this._.apply(null,arguments);}.apply({navigator:typeof window!='undefined'?window.navigator:null,document:typeof window!='undefined'?window.document:null}, arguments);}\n).apply(null, arguments)","args":[{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"cae111e7-8b5a-6747-8835-b4fa9d8d0c42"},"readOnly"]}
2017-09-01 15:04:51 DEBUG Selenium      > {"Accept"=>"application/json", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Content-Length"=>"6725"}
2017-09-01 15:04:51 INFO Selenium <- {"value":null}
2017-09-01 15:04:51 INFO Selenium -> POST session/02500e7f-0c52-1e40-b151-39b2d857d17f/element/cae111e7-8b5a-6747-8835-b4fa9d8d0c42/clear
2017-09-01 15:04:51 INFO Selenium <- {"value": {}}
2017-09-01 15:04:51 INFO Selenium -> POST session/02500e7f-0c52-1e40-b151-39b2d857d17f/element/cae111e7-8b5a-6747-8835-b4fa9d8d0c42/value
2017-09-01 15:04:51 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/02500e7f-0c52-1e40-b151-39b2d857d17f/element/cae111e7-8b5a-6747-8835-b4fa9d8d0c42/value | {"value":["s","a","n","d","e","e","p",".","k","u","m","a","r","@","v","o","c","u","s",".","c","o","m",".","a","u"],"text":"sandeep.kumar@vocus.com.au"}
2017-09-01 15:04:51 DEBUG Selenium      > {"Accept"=>"application/json", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Content-Length"=>"151"}
2017-09-01 15:04:51 INFO Selenium <- {"value":{"error":"invalid argument","message":"Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string","stacktrace":"stack backtrace:\n   0:        0x10f2b179e - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h5d936e38aaf1110e\n   1:        0x10f2b1edc - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::h90c05c8c72e0f6cd\n   2:        0x10f1f5ca0 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteSession::response::h08aa31b0bbd51dd7\n   3:        0x10f1f3655 - _$LT$geckodriver..marionette..MarionetteHandler$u20$as$u20$webdriver..server..WebDriverHandler$LT$geckodriver..marionette..GeckoExtensionRoute$GT$$GT$::handle_command::h5bcbc41bc7c51981\n   4:        0x10f1c1830 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h532e0d8672b70b60\n   5:        0x10f33270a - __rust_maybe_catch_panic\n   6:        0x10f1d2896 - _$LT$F$u20$as$u20$alloc..boxed..FnBox$LT$A$GT$$GT$::call_box::h4a379663166b1095\n   7:        0x10f330ba4 - std::sys::imp::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::hf410a68837ea407b\n   8:     0x7fffcbbff93a - _pthread_body\n   9:     0x7fffcbbff886 - _pthread_start"}}
  Scenario: QB Ethernet UI validations # features/ui_validations_vocusone.feature:13
    Given QB Ethernet UI validations   # features/step_definitions/ui_validations_vocusone.rb:61
      Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError)
      ./features/support/pages/page.rb:35:in `block (3 levels) in generate'
      ./features/step_definitions/ui_validations_vocusone.rb:63:in `/^QB Ethernet UI validations$/'
      features/ui_validations_vocusone.feature:14:in `Given QB Ethernet UI validations'
2017-09-01 15:04:51 INFO Selenium -> DELETE session/02500e7f-0c52-1e40-b151-39b2d857d17f
1504242291281   Marionette      INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted
2017-09-01 15:04:51 INFO Selenium <- {"value": {}}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace? And/or add this before code execution: `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug` and link to a gist of the log?

Comment: Updated the question details with the stack trace. Thank you.

Comment: Any update on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at my own question that I posted and also at my code. Having realised that I mentioned the `bundle update` screwed the executable code, I had a look at my `Gemfile`. I am able to find that the culprit is `geckodriver-helper` which is breaking the `geckodriver` that I installed through `homebrew`.

Lesson learnt: Install either through homebrew or gemfile but not both